# saving data in sqlite using dbhelper

Tags: android

i need a little help. I am trying to save some data to sqllite and i keep getting toast that is no sucessfull. Below is my code and i have the same code for the second sqlite and it works? what seems to be the issue here (maybe the time).

My XML:

```
  <EditText
        android:id="@+id/moja_bolecina"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Moja bolečina" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/moje_zdravilo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Zdravilo" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/kolicina_zdravila"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Zdravilo vzamem (primer 3x dnevno)" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="OB:"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/ura_1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="time" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/ura_2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="time" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/ura_3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="time"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/shrani_nastavitve"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Shrani" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/pregled_nastavitev"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Pregled Trenutnih nastavitev" />
```

My DBhelper:

```
public class DBhelper_nastavitve extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "vas_podatki.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "nastavitve_uporabnika";
    public static final String COL_1 = "vrsta_bolecine";
    public static final String COL_2 = "zravilo_proti_bolecini";
    public static final String COL_3 = "zdravilo_vzamem";
    public static final String COL_4 = "prva_ura";
    public static final String COL_5 = "druga_ura";
    public static final String COL_6 = "tretja_ura";
    public static final String COLUMN_TIME_STAMP  = "timeStamp ";



    public DBhelper_nastavitve(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table "+ TABLE_NAME + "(COL_1 STRING, COL_2 STRING,COL_3 STRING, COL_4  STRING, COL_5 STRING, COL_6 STRING, COLUMN_TIME_STAMP TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)");

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS"+ TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);

    }

    public boolean insertData(String vrsta_bolecine, String zravilo_proti_bolecini, String zdravilo_vzamem, String prva_ura, String druga_ura, String tretja_ura){
        SQLiteDatabase db_nastavitve = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL_1,vrsta_bolecine);
        contentValues.put(COL_2,zravilo_proti_bolecini);
        contentValues.put(COL_3,zdravilo_vzamem);
        contentValues.put(COL_4,prva_ura);
        contentValues.put(COL_5,druga_ura);
        contentValues.put(COL_6,tretja_ura);
        long reuslt = db_nastavitve.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues);
        if (reuslt == -1)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
}
```

Main Class:

```
public class nastavitve extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button gumb_poslji;
    DBhelper_nastavitve myDb_nastavitve;
    EditText bolecina, zdravilo, kolicina_zdravila, ura1, ura2, ura3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.nastavitve);

        gumb_poslji=(Button)findViewById(R.id.shrani_nastavitve);
        myDb_nastavitve = new DBhelper_nastavitve(this);
        bolecina = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.moja_bolecina);
        zdravilo = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.moje_zdravilo);
        kolicina_zdravila = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.kolicina_zdravila);
        ura1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ura_1);
        ura2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ura_2);
        ura3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ura_3);

        AddData();

    }
    public void AddData(){

        gumb_poslji.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                boolean pregled_vnosa = myDb_nastavitve.insertData(
                        bolecina.getText().toString(),
                        zdravilo.getText().toString(),
                        kolicina_zdravila.getText().toString(),
                        ura1.getText().toString(),
                        ura2.getText().toString(),
                        ura3.getText().toString()
                );
                if (pregled_vnosa==true)
                    Toast.makeText(nastavitve.this, "Vnos uspešen",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                else
                    Toast.makeText(nastavitve.this, "Vnos neuspešen!!!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: put your stacktrace here please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so i changed this line:

```
 db.execSQL("create table "+ TABLE_NAME + "(COL_1 STRING, COL_2 STRING,COL_3 STRING, COL_4  STRING, COL_5 STRING, COL_6 STRING, COLUMN_TIME_STAMP TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)");
```

to this:

```
db.execSQL("create table "+ TABLE_NAME + "(vrsta_bolecine STRING, zravilo_proti_bolecini STRING,zdravilo_vzamem STRING, prva_ura  STRING, druga_ura STRING, tretja_ura STRING, COLUMN_TIME_STAMP TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)");
```

And it works.